# To connect create-react-app reactJs with mysql

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I have problem in connecting my create-react-app with mysql using npm.

Its working in nodejs when i tried seperately without npm. But, When i trying to connect using npm install mysql, It throws me an error...

> TypeError: http.IncomingMessage is undefined
>   ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js

Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection =mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'user',
    password: '',
    database: 'reactproject'
});

connection.connect(function(err){
    if(!err) {
        console.log("Database is connected ... nn");
    } else {
        console.log("Error connecting database ... nn");
    }
});
```

Comment: React runs in the browser and can't connect to databases. See this answer for more on how to use React and a database together: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52378352/error-using-postgres-with-a-newly-created-react-app-module-not-found-cant-res/52381129#52381129

Answer (score 0):

This will not work from react-app, since react code will run from client side.
You should use my-sql connection in different app and run in different port and call as api connection.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Adding from an @ashik answer is correct, but if you still want to use MySQL and reactjs simultaneously, you can start by creating your own boilerplate, there you can use MySQL on the server side and create APi/web service without having to separate the APi server and client projects reactjs.